# Which webcontrol should I use to list days off in a time period by Supervisor then employee

Tags: c#-4.0, web-controls

I am looking to create something that looks like this.

- Supervisor name

  - Employee name

    - 3/4/2012 sick day
    - 3/5/2012 sick day
    - 3/7/2012 vaction day
  - Employee #2 name

    - 3/6/2012 jury duty

what kind of control should I be using? I have a database that has the relevent data and I can create a view to get it to look like anything I would need.

Comment: I was looking at the Group template for the listview control but I don't know how it works I would love to see an example of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use asp Tree view Control. Its may help you below link

http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/WalkThru/WalkThrough.aspx#PopulateOnDemandTreeView

Answer (score 1):

TreeView?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx

Comment: I'm more looking forsomething that can take a data source that
has rows like

supervisor emp1 dateoff reason code
supervisor emp1 dateoff reason code
supervisor emp1 dateoff reason code
supervisor emp2 dateoff reason code

then apply the grouping for me that is the tricky part. Does treeview do that?